# Creating hidden screen sessions which are not visible via "screen -ls" command

Tags: command-line, gnu-screen

Is there any way to have `screen` sessions that aren't visible via `screen -ls` command? If so, then what's the access method to these screens?

Any screen that is created by a `screen -S <Name>` will be shown in the output of `screen -ls`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These locations mentioned in [`man screen`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/screen.1.html) could be of interest:

```
$SCREENDIR/S-<login>
/local/screens/S-<login>          Socket directories (default)
/usr/tmp/screens/S-<login>        Alternate socket directories.
```

Example:

```
% mkdir foo; chmod 0700 foo;
% SCREENDIR=$PWD/foo screen -S foo -d -m sleep inf
% screen -ls
No Sockets found in /var/folders/vy/t__dhyrs3d5dd_bvk6mj5t480000gn/T/.screen.

% SCREENDIR=$PWD/foo screen -ls
There is a screen on:
    67294.foo   (Detached)
1 Socket in /Users/muru/foo.
```

So, you could use different `SCREENDIR`s to keep separate sets of sessions.